# Windows 8 missing Hardware acceleration setting

Tags: windows-8

I was following this tutorial to solve my TeamViewer issue at http://teamviewerforums.com/index.php?topic=1991.0 it eats all CPU on remote PC and someone said that disabling hardware acceleration on the remote PC it solves the problem. I got no setting for Hardware acceleration to disable it.

Just Google any tutorial how to disable it, I always get to the Troubleshoot tab and it simply doesn't have the option. It's empty in that area where it's supposed to be a setting.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Do you have the required hardware for hardware acceleration?

Comment: I don't have a "Properties" in my right-click context menu from the desktop.. some images would be appreciated, both of what you see and the tutorial you are following

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible your machine doesn't have any hardware acceleration for Windows functions. If it's a budget laptop with integrated graphics, it may simply not offer any graphics API for Windows to use, so everything has to be done in software. You might also have an issue where your hardware either isn't recognized or you're using a generic driver that doesn't report any hardware capabilities.

Comment: How do I check if I don't have it? Maybe somehow via registry or cmd or something?

Comment: @user3108268 Look in the device manager.

Comment: Look in the device manager for what exactly?

Comment: Possibly on the "Details" tab when you open the device. Sorry, I don't have Win8.1 installed here, so I can't say for sure.  You might have better luck trying to find a support forum for your machine/motherboard/chipset where you can ask someone.

Comment: I need to look on Motherboard details tab for something that says Hardware acceleration?

Comment: I was thinking more of getting your motherboard model number and checking with the manufacturer to see if you can get the specs and see if they say if they provide any hardware acceleration.